# Noise spectral density for GW detector

Tags: gravitational-waves, power, noise

I am reading the book [Gravitational waves by Maggiore](https://books.google.com/books?id=AqVpQgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). On page 337 in Eq. (7.6) he defines the noise spectral density as

$$<\tilde{n}^*(f)\tilde{n}(f')>=\delta(f-f')\frac{1}{2}S_n(f)$$.

I want to understand what the $<\cdots>$ operation means.

Let $n(t)$ be the noise function which has been measured at $N$ different times $t_0,t_1,\cdots t_{N-1}$. The time interval between measurements is $\Delta t:=T/(N-1)$. The different measurements are referred to as $n_0, n_1, \cdots n_{N-1}$. We define

$$t_i:= \Delta t\times\, i=\frac{T}{N-1} i$$.

In frequency space we define

$$\omega_i=2\pi f_i:=2\pi \frac{i}{T}\frac{N-1}{N}$$

The discrete Fourier transformation is defined as

$$\tilde{n}_i=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}n_j e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{N}ij}=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}n_j e^{-i\omega_i t_j}=:\tilde{n}(\omega_j)$$

and the inverse:
$$n_j=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\tilde{n}_i e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}ij}=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\tilde{n}_i e^{i\omega_i t_j}=:n(t_j)$$

Now I guess when Maggiore writes $<\tilde{n}^*(f_m)\tilde{n}(f_k)>$ he means something like

$$<\tilde{n}^*(f_m)\tilde{n}(f_k)>= T \sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\tilde{n}^*(\omega_m)\tilde{n}(\omega_k+\omega_x)= T \sum_{x=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j j'=0}^{N-1}n_j^*n_{j'} e^{i\omega_m t_j-i(\omega_k+\omega_x) t_{j'}}$$

I could evaluate this further by using $\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}e^{-i \omega_x t_j}=N\delta_{j0}$
but I don't see how I should get a result that has $\delta(\omega_m-\omega_k)$ in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot speak for a GW spectrum analyzer specifically but in general, the mathematical definition of the spectrum of a stationary stochastic process $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is to take the Fourier transform of a finite segment

$$\mathbf{X}_T (u) = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \mathbf{x}(t) e^{-2\pi i u t}dt ,$$

then after *ensemble* averaging form the following limit

$$S(u) =  \lim_{T \to \infty} {\frac{\textbf{Av} \{|\mathbf{X}_T (u)|^2\}}{T}}$$

In all *practical* spectrum analyzer instruments though, equipment such as by Hewlett-Packard (Agilent, Keysight), Anritsu, Tektronix, etc., the following is really done. The output of a bandpass filter whose impulse response is represented by, say, $h(t,u,\delta)=\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{u-\delta/2}^{u+\delta/2}e^{i2\pi vt}dv=e^{i2\pi ut} \textrm{sinc}(\delta t)$, is passed through a square-law detector and then averaged by a so-called *video* filter that is essentially an integrator:

$$h(t,u,\delta)=\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{u+\delta/2}^{u+\delta/2}\\
\mathbf{y}(t,u,\delta)=\mathbf{x(t)}\otimes h(t,u,\delta)\\
S'(u,A,\delta)=\frac{1}{A}\int_{A/2}^{A/2} dt|\mathbf{y}(t,u,\delta)|^2$$

This $S'(u,A,\delta)$ is an *instrumental* approximation to $S(u)$ and it is probably what is meant by your $S_n(f)$ with $f=u$. The $\delta(f-f')$ means that the spectral components at $f$ and $f'$ are uncorrelated with each other, which is usually true for a wideband normal noise process.

Comment: What does the operation $Av{|X_T(u)|^2}$ do?

Comment: It is the ensemble average of the FT squared segments of length $T$. Each of those $T$-long FT pieces represent a frequency *resolution* of the signal into $\approx \tfrac{1}{T}$ wide frequency bins. If  the process is ergodic then the ensemble averaging can be replaced by a time domain filter, for historical treasons it is called the "video" filter. Spectrum analysis does not work without the video filter because $\frac{|\mathbf{X}_T (u)|^2}{T}$ (periodogram) of the normal noise is not a *consistent* estimator, that is its variance does not go to zero as $T\to\infty$, with averaging it does.

Comment: For normal noise it can be shown that $\mathbf{Var}[\tfrac {|\mathbf{X}_T (u)|^2}{T}] \ge \mathbf {Ave} [\tfrac{ |\mathbf{X}_T (u)|^2} {T}]$ for any $T$ segment, the periodogram $\tfrac{|\mathbf{X}_T (u)|^2}{T}$ does not converge to the underlying spectrum anywhere, but its *expectation*, ie., ensemble average, does.